# Facebook: How do you display the cost of an item in Local Currency

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am planning to implement a Storefront in Facebook. Is there a was to show the price of the items in Local currency? For example an American user would see prices in USD, whereas a British user would see GBP etc. I have created the OG product object.

The FB pay UI-Dialogbox is showing the local currency correctly, I am trying to show the same amount in my Store screen. For example the below code shows the FB pay UI-Dialogbox with $26.54 USD for the item. But in my OG product object I have specified £17.49. How do I show $26.54 USD in my Store screen with out specifying it in the OG product object? Is this possible?

My code

```js
    FB.ui({
          method: 'pay',
          action: 'purchaseitem',
          product: 'http://www.site.com/FB_og/coins_3800.html',
          quantity: 1,
          test_currency: "USD"
    },
    callback);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head prefix=
    "og: http://ogp.me/ns# 
     fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
     product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    <meta property="og:type"                   content="og:product" />
    <meta property="og:title"                  content="3800 Coins" />
    <meta property="og:plural_title"           content="3800 Coins" />
    <meta property="og:image"                  content="http://www.site.com/FB_og/coin.png" />
    <meta property="og:description"            content="Buy Coins" />
    <meta property="og:url"                    content="http://www.site.com/FB_og/coins_3800.html" />
    <meta property="product:price:amount"      content="17.49"/>
    <meta property="product:price:currency"    content="GBP"/>
  </head>
```